# How to access font color of a text within a textbox using python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have not been able to find a straight forward answer to this, and it should be relatively simple:

Using python-pptx, I am trying to read the color of the font of the text inside a textbox on a slide.

I am not trying to change the color of the text but rather I am reading in a PowerPoint slide and I can access the text, shape, end points etc., but I also need to access the font color.

Currently I am trying:

```
for shape in slide.shapes:
    if shape.has_text_frame:
        text = shape.text_frame.text
        if shape.shape_type == 17:
            try:
                text_color = shape.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb
            except AttributeError:
                fill_color = None
        else:
            text_color = None
```

but its giving an `Attribute Error: no .rgb property on color type '_NoneColor'`

Comment: You should provide more detail and code for others to be able to help you better.
Also, `.rgb` property is only available when font color has been explicitly set on text.

Comment: ok ty, do you know how would i access the font color after its been read in?

Comment: The thing is when the color has not been explicitly set on the text itself, reading in this way will return `None`. But when it is set, your code should work properly. You can even use your own code to set a default color by assigning `RGBColor(255, 0, 0)` to it. But as I said, you can't read it if not set explicitly.

Comment: doesnt that defeat the point? because im trying to read the color as it is imported from the existing ppt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font belongs to a run. So `paragraphs[0].runs[0]` should get you to the font object.

Comment: that worked! You're my hero